# how to get value multiple tags in javascript using the id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the name of the two `<p>` elements in my html file using id after the button is clicked. but in my code, when I clicked the button, i it only outputs "print". How can I do this?

This is my HTML code:

```
<p id="name" name="print">hey</p>     
<p id="name" name="this">hey</p>     
<button id="btn11">test11</button>
```

This is my javascript code:

```
$("#btn11").click(function(){
    alert($("#name").attr("name"));
});
```

Comment: Id be unique in HTML

Comment: Use `class` instead of `id`

Answer (score 4):

Id should be unique in HTML. Instead of id use class like this

Html:

```
<p class="name" name="print">hey</p>     
<p class="name" name="this">hey</p>     
<button id="btn11">test11</button>
```

jquery:

```
$("#btn11").click(function(){
   var getName = $(".name").map(function() { 
        return $(this).attr("name");
    }).get();
    console.log(getName);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

use class instead of ID and

```
<p class= "name" name = "print">hey</p>

<p class= "name" name = "this">hey/p>

<button id="btn11">test11</button>

$("#btn11").click(function(){ 
  $('.name').each(function () {
   alert( $(this).attr('name'));
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`id` should be unique in html. You should use `class` attribute:

```
<p class="name" data-name="print">hey</p>
<p class="name" data-name="this">hey</p>
<button id="btn11">test11</button>

$("#btn11").click(function(){
    $.each($(".name"), function(i, v) {
        console.log($(v).data("name"))
    })
});
```

Also, `name` is not a property of `<p>` tag. See [Element.name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/name)

Answer (score 1):

You should not use dupicate IDs in HTML, still you want to use the the same here is the code which works as you expected

```
$("#btn11").click(function () {
    $("p[id='name']").each(function (e) {
        alert($(this).attr("name"));
    });
});
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ds6nsa5L/)

Answer (score 0):

id should be unique. not recommended to use duplicate id's in the html document. 
still if you want continue with your old code.

you can also do like this

```
document.querySelectorAll('p[id=name]')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Extremely bad practice.

Two separate elements should NOT contain the same ID nor name. Apply a class name and iterate (using an each or map) through the class name. There are many ways to do this (I already see some solid examples here). Then, make use the data attribute to store unique data per each element.